# How can I use async or parallelism in Powershell class constructors?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell class (a couple, actually; it's nested) that I'm creating instances of in a loop.  The constructor has a bunch of tasks that populate the object (including those nested classes, which also populate themselves).  However, those tasks are sometimes a bit slow, and I'd like to be able to execute multiple tasks and instantiate multiple objects concurrently.  How can I do that within Powershell?

Example class:

```bash
Class Server {
  Server([string] $ServerName) {
    $this.ServerName = $ServerName
    $this.ComputerSystem = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ServerName 
    $this.OperatingSystem = Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ServerName
    $this.Bios = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $ServerName
    $this.NetworkAdapter = Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration  -ComputerName $ServerName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is **no *convenient* solution** as of PowerShell 7.3.0, because **properties in PowerShell custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es cannot be implemented by way of accessor *methods***.

- Adding this ability in a future version has been proposed in [GitHub issue #2219](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219) - years ago.

The following:

- uses *methods* (e.g., `.Bios()` in lieu of properties (e.g. `.Bios`), so that the "property value" can be retrieved dynamically; the backing instance property, which is hidden with the `hidden` attribute, is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) that maps "property names" to their values.
- uses [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob), which *ships with* PowerShell (Core) 7+, and *can be installed* in Windows PowerShell with `Install-Module ThreadJob`, to asynchronously launch thread-based jobs on construction, which perform the `Get-CimInstance` calls in the background.

```bash
Class Server {

    # Instance variables:
    [string] $ServerName
    # A hidden map (hashtable) that maps what are conceptually properties to the
    # commands that retrieve their values, via thread jobs.
    # Note that the static values defined here are *script blocks*, which are replaced
    # with what their *invocation* evaluates to in the constructor.
    # Note: By default, up to 5 thread jobs are permitted to run at a time.
    #       You can modify this limit with -ThrottleLimit on the first Start-ThreadJob call,
    #       which then applies to all subsequent Start-ThreadJob calls that do not themselves
    #       use -ThrottleLimit in the same session.
    hidden [hashtable] $_jobsMap = @{
      ComputerSystem = { Start-ThreadJob { Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $using:ServerName } }
      OperatingSystem = { Start-ThreadJob { Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $using:ServerName } }
      Bios = { Start-ThreadJob { Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $using:ServerName } }
      NetworkAdapter = { Start-ThreadJob { Get-CimInstance Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $using:ServerName } }
    }
  
    # Constructor
    Server([string] $ServerName) {
        $this.ServerName = $ServerName
        # Asynchronously start the thread jobs that populate the "property"
        # values, i.e. the entries of the $this._jobsMap hashtable.
        foreach ($key in @($this._jobsMap.Keys)) {
          # Replace each predefined script block with the result of its
          # *invocation*, i.e. with an object describing each launched thread job.
          $this._jobsMap[$key] = & $this._jobsMap[$key]
        }
    }
  
    # Methods that act like property accessors.
    [object] ComputerSystem() {
        return $this.get('ComputerSystem')
    }
    [object] OperatingSystem() {
        return $this.get('OperatingSystem')
    }
    [object] Bios() {
        return $this.get('Bios')
    }
    [object] NetworkAdapter() {
        return $this.get('NetworkAdapter')
    }
  
    # Hidden helper method that returns the value of interest,
    # making sure that a value has been received from the relevant
    # thread job first.
    hidden [object] get($propName) {
        if ($this._jobsMap[$propName] -is [System.Management.Automation.Job]) {
            # Note that any error-stream output from the jobs
            # is *not* automatically passed through; -ErrorVariable is used
            # to collect any error(s), which are translated into a script-terminating
            # error with `throw`
            $e = $null
            $this._jobsMap[$propName] = $this._jobsMap[$propName] | 
              Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob -ErrorVariable e
            if ($e) {
              throw $e[0]
            }
        }
        return $this._jobsMap[$propName]
    }
  
    # Method that indicates whether *all* "properties" have finished
    # initializing.
    [bool] IsInitialized() {
      $pendingJobs = $this._jobsMap.Values.Where({ $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.Job] })
      return $pendingJobs.Count -eq 0 -or $pendingJobs.Where({ $_.State -in 'NotStarted', 'Running' }, 'First').Count -eq 0
    }
  
  }
```

Example use:

```bash
# Instantiate [Server], which asynchronously starts the thread jobs
# that will populate the properties.
$server = [Server]::new('.')

# Access a "property" by way of its helper method, which
# waits for the job to complete first, if necessary.
$server.Bios() 

# Test if all property values have been retrieved yet.
$server.IsInitialized()
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot but it'll take some refactoring.  Couple follow-up questions: how would you recommend handling checking that all objects have completed initializing?  I presume another method that can examine all the properties.  Also, these objects also have nested objects and the whole stack will be instantiated through a loop, so I can imagine this spawning hundreds of threads.  I see there's `ThrottleLimit` - how would I make use of that effectively?

Comment: @end-user, please see my update. The code has been restructured to use a hashtable as the backing variable. An `.IsInitialized()` method has been added. See the source-code comments re `-ThrottleLimit`, which controls how many threads can run at a time. Whenever you use `-ThrottleLimit`, the value takes effect session-wide.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  An additional complexity: some of the class's properties are other classes which I'd like to also use the same multi-threaded initialization for.  So, I'm thinking I'd enhance the `IsInitialized` method to also loop through all child objects and call their `IsInitialized()` methods.

Comment: Makes sense, @end-user, but in order to keep the length and complexity of this answer manageable, I won't try to add the nesting aspect to it; I think that future readers will be able to figure out how to extend the technique to nested classes themselves.